# Examples of Banach $^*$-algebras where $^*$ is not an isometry

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, involutions

I'm reading up on $C^*$-algebras at the moment, and in the Wiki article (for instance) on the topic they note that the condition $||a^*a||=||a||^2$ implies that the $^*$-involution is an isometry.

But what are examples of Banach $^*$-algebras where the $^*$-involution is not an isometry? While there must be a reason why it's noted in particular that the $C^*$ condition implies that $||a^*||=||a||$, I don't know any examples of a Banach $^*$-algebra $B$ where $||a^*||\neq ||a||$ for some $a\in B$.

As a bonus question, what are some examples of Banach $^*$-algebras, where the $^*$-involution is an isometry, but the $C^*$ condition does not hold?

Comment: One such example would be $\ell^1 (\mathbb Z)$ endowed with convolution product and the involution being the componentwise complex conjugation.

Comment: @AntonioClaire I assume that's an example for the bonus question, right? Or am I missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the bonus question: Consider the Disk algebra $A(\mathbb{D})$ (the continuous functions on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ which are holomorphic on
$\mathbb{D}$, endowed with the maximum norm $||\cdot||$) and set
$$
f^\ast(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}.
$$
Then $\ast$ is an involution. It is an isometry, but for $f(z)=z+i$ we have
$f^\ast(z)=z-i$, hence $f^\ast (z)f(z)=z^2+1$. Thus $||f^\ast f||= 2$ but
$||f||^2=4$. Also note that $g(z)=z$ is selfadjoint with spectrum
$\sigma(g)=\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. This also shows that we have no $C^\ast$-algebra, as in that case the spectrum of a selfadjoint element has to be real.

Edit: Concerning the underlying question: Consider the matrix algebra $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ endowed with the row-sum norm $||\cdot||_\infty$. This is a Banach algebra, as the row-sum norm is an operator norm. Let $\ast$ be the usual matrix involution. Then $||A^\ast||_\infty = ||A||_1$ (with $||\cdot||_1$ the column-sum norm). It is easy to find matrices with $||A||_1 \not= ||A||_\infty$, for those
$||A^\ast||_\infty \not= ||A||_\infty$.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand the Disk algebra example fully: is the reason why we only consider continuous functions on the closed unit disc that we want to make sure that there aren't any functions in the algebra that are unbounded with regards to the supremum norm? Because it seems like the chosen involution is what causes the real problems for the $C^*$ condition in this example. Or can the example break down if we pick some other nonempty and open precompact set in $\C$?

Comment: I think the domain is quite variable in this example. Of course it has to be symmetric with respect to the real axis. Moreover, if you consider bounded holomorphic functions it should work the same way. For example $A(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ can be replaced by $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ (the BA of all bounded holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$). Even holomorphy is not a material fact. I think BAs of continuous functions such as $C(\overline{\mathbb{D}},\mathbb{C})$ are ok. So you are right: It is the structure of the involution what causes the problem.